# Combine list nodes

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

If we are given a linked list then we have to manipulate such that even indexed nodes are arranged together and odd indexed nodes are arranged together after even indexed nodes.

The following linked list `1-->2-->3-->4-->5-->6` , should output:

```
 2-->4-->6-->1-->3-->5
```

Comment: Are you looking for the code? Can you explain your the efforts you put in? The easiest way is move all the even numbered nodes to the front. You should be able to do this with the basic linked list operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say this is your list:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

First you need to assign a `pointer` to the `head` of the list like this:

```
node_t * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Then using a `for` loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<size_of_your_list; i= i+2){
             if(i % 2 == 0){
              printf("%d",head->val);
            }
            head = head->next;
    }
   for(int i =1 ; i<size_of_your_list; i=i+2){
            if(i % 2 == 1){
              printf("%d",head->val);
            }
            head = head->next;
    }
```

Note that this code only prints. It does not change your list.

Comment: if `printf("%d",head->val);` does not work try : `printf("%p",head->val);`

Comment: Actually we have to modify the list rather than simply printing it . And moreover  using your code , I am unable to get where is the index stored related to node , I mean as we did i%2 ==1 or i%2==0 , so how do we know which value of i is used for that node , or do we assume here that already there is a field of index associated with each node .

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Edited my code a little bit. You can assume that the first node corresponds to `i = 0` , the second `i=1` e.t.c.

Comment: But we have to in general modify the list right and as per ur logic it will print first node first but we have to show 2nd node first

Answer (score 0):

```
node_t *cursor = input_list;
while(cursor) {
    if(cursor->value % 2 == 0)
        append(output_list, cursor->value)
    cursor = cursor->next;
}

cursor = input_list;
while(cursor) {
    if(cursor->value % 2 == 1)
        append(output_list, cursor->value)
    cursor = cursor->next;
}
```